# questions of a simple web crawler

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, web-crawler

I recently is learning web crawler with python, and I have some questions in a small example code. It has a local html file which contains some images and a .py file which crawls it.

The html file 'first_web.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>First web</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <ul class="article">
            <li>
                <img src="1.jpg" width="100" height="90">
                <h3>first</h3>
                <p>This is first</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="2.jpg" width="100" height="90">
                <h3>second</h3>
                <p>This is second</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="3.jpg" width="100" height="90">
                <h3>Third</h3>
                <p>This is Third</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy;Alex</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the .py file:

```
from lxml import etree
f = open('first_web.html','r',encoding='utf-8')
# print(f.read())
html = etree.HTML(f.read())
for i in range(1,4):
    img = html.xpath('//div[2]/ul/li[{}]/img/@src'.format(i))[0]
    print(img)
```

I would like to ask what do li[{}], .format[i], @src and [0] mean in this line of code?

```
img = html.xpath('//div[2]/ul/li[{}]/img/@src'.format(i))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is a placeholder, and becomes the value of `i` because of the `.format()` call.

```
>>> print 'My name is {}'.format('Steve')
My name is Steve
```

`[0]` means "the first item in this list", i.e. `html.xpath(...)` returns more than one value, and we only want the first one.

```
>>> mylist = [ 'Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas' ]
>>> print mylist[0]
Apples
```

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot! May I ask what's the @src for?

Comment: `@src` is the xpath way of asking for the `src` attribute of the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This line makes use of the python [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) feature to create an [xpath expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath).

It is a little tricky here to separate python string formatting from the xpath expression.

`li[{}]` is part of xpath were `{}` is the index of the `li` element you want to query. As you have a loop around this and want the value of the python variable `i` to be included in the expression. `{}` will be replaced by format with the value of `i`.

`@src` is part of xpath and tells something like: "Please give me the value of the src-attribute from the selected img-tag".

The final `[0]` is there because `xpath` always returns a list and you want the first element. In fact your expression makes sure that there is only one result.

If you want this to work with any number of images you might completely drop the range loop and the formatting part and directly make use of xpath:

```
for img in html.xpath('//div[2]/ul/li/img/@src'):
    print(img)
```

This way you query the HTML for all img tags in the list of the second div container and fetch their src attribute.